# Instantiating classes with single-argument constructor via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am working on the menuscreen of a game and I would like to call the appropriate screens chosen by the user via reflection. I have an ArrayList containing the different classnames for the screens as strings - they all are subclasses of class "Screen" ("GameScreen", "HighScoreScreen" and so on). The constructor of the Screen-class takes an instance of the Game-class as an argument - e.g. `game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));`.

I have tried this:

```
String classname = menuentries.get(cursorpos).getClassname();
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classname); //seems to work fine
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(Game.class); // <- throws exception
game.setScreen((Screen)ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {game}));
```

but it gave me this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: screens.GameScreen.<init>(java.lang.Class)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The constructor does not exist. After you initialize the constructor try doing `ctor.setAccessible(true)` and try creating a new instance. Although if it throws an exception upon retrieving the constructor, it is probably safe to assume that it doesn't exist which means you are passing in the wrong argument types. It would be nice if you showed the constructors from the `GameScreen` class though.

Comment: Right off the bat, I'd say this is a weird use for reflection. If you are set in your ways, let us see the full source of GameScreen, and any other screen that throws this error.

Comment: @JoshM He said that the line where he assigns ctor is throwing the exception. Adding that after it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Why do you not use an ArrayList of instances of the subclasses of `Screen`?

Comment: @ChrisBode Yeah my bad, edited comment.

Comment: @JoshM: I just set the constructor of GameScreen from package to public, then it worked (everything is in the same package oO). Thank you!

Comment: @FrankPI Just to see how this would work via reflection I guess :) and maybe because I don't want the screens to be instantiated upfront.